# Generating CSS from PHP

Tags: php, css

I've read a lot a blogs and forums but I'm still having trouble getting this to work. I allow my users to change their user account style sheet.

I've added the `<?php header("Content-type: text/css"); ?>` to the top of the style.php and I've included that file into my html.

But all I can see is

```
<style>
box {
color:#;
background-color:#;
</style>
```

The values aren't showing up. Any pointers?

Comment: Included style.php into your HTML?

Comment: no closing }  or is this a typo?

Comment: @user765476: Probably a typo and definitely not related.

Comment: If you're including it (like `include ...`) then setting the header is not needed. You only need that if you reference your style sheet. (like `<link ...` or `@import ...`)

Comment: We need to see your PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to take a wild guess here since we can't see your stylesheet...

You aren't using `echo` for the values.

Either that, or as [Rytmis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394881/generating-css-from-php/6394903#6394903) said, the values are in fact empty.

No point in trying to set the content type header if you're using `include` to output the CSS in a `<style>` block, you should be referencing the file with a `<link>` tag.

Comment: I am using it for the values. That's whats puzzling me!

Comment: OK, so does `echo` work with a static string? Like, does `echo "#FF00FF";` work? And are you 100% there are values? Turned on [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) etc.?

Comment: I think it's something to do with the way I implemented it. Rather than trying to fix it, re-writing the entire thing maybe better.

Comment: It's most definitely "something to do with the way you implemented it" :) GL - see my edit as well, let me know if it needs clarification or you understand.

Comment: I found the error! It was "most definitely" the way I implemented it. I didn't fetch the array. I just directly tried to call on the indexes from the resource. :P

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special to generating CSS as opposed to generating HTML, so if your values aren't showing up, chances are there are no values there. First, check your assumptions: see if you've got values in your data source. Then, if you do, try debugging to narrow down to the point where you no longer have them, and there's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

the header, if you use one, must precede ANY content.
you are better off writing the css directly into the page (my first suggestion) or *maybe* using a temporary file if you can find a way to write it to the server and access it on the browser.

otherwise, you have the problem of "how to I point my html document to a spontaneously generated css file with no content? there's no filepath!

unless of course you use something like #CDATA or #PCDATA I think and BASE64 encode your document and thus embed it inside style tags.  I have seen this trick done with src attributes on img tags.  no filename, just straight data feed.  there are examples on the internet, but my browser has been zapping important entries from the bookmarks lately (firefox).
good way to hide your source code, terrible for maintainability.